# how to precompile a dust template

Tags: dust.js, dustc

```
dust-compiler -s controllers/inbox/views/inbox.dust -d    public/js/custom/inbox/messages.js
```

but i am getting error

```
 if (err) throw err;
               ^
Error: ENOTDIR, scandir 'C:\jbk\buy2gthr-master\controllers\inbox\views\inbox.dust'
    at Error (native)
```

i have inbox.dust file:

```
{>"../../../layout/layout"/}

 {<css-content}
 {/css-content}
 {<page-content}
 {/<page-content}
     <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-tmpl">
                  {title}
                    <ul>
                        {#data}
                        <li>{name}</li>{~n}
                        {/data}
                    </ul>
     </script>
**<div id="output"></div>**
 {/page-content}
 {<script-content}
 <script src='/js/custom/inbox/inbox.js'></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dustjs-linkedin/2.7.2/dust-full.js'></script>
  {/script-content}
```

and inbox.js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = {
        "title": "Famous People", 
        "names" : [{ "name": "Larry" },{ "name": "Curly" },{ "name": "Moe" }]
    }

    var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
    var compiled = dust.compile(source, "intro");
    console.log(compiled);

    dust.loadSource(compiled);

    dust.render("intro", data, function(err, out) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else
        console.log(out);

        $("#output").html(out);
    });
});
```

still i am gettting

```
<div id="output"><ul></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what dust compiler you're using, but just use `dustc` -- it comes with Dust.

You can read about [all the dustc API options](http://www.dustjs.com/docs/dustc-api/), but to precompile a single file you'd do something like

```
dustc controllers/inbox/views/inbox.dust --output=public/js/custom/inbox/messages.js
```

dustc compiles templates using absolute names instead of relative ones, because Dust is not filesystem-aware. Unless you've specifically set up your `dust.onLoad` function to handle relative paths, you'll want to make your includes look something like `{> "inbox/messages" /}`.

Comment: ..now i am using dustc and now i have a messages.dust file ,so using dustc **dustc controllers/inbox/views/messages.dust --output=public/js/custom/inbox/messages.js** ,and in main inbox.dust file i have included messages.js ,dust-core.js and main inbox.js ,so in main inbox.js by which name** i have to render to template**

Comment: dust.render('messages', data, function(err, out) {
  document.getElementById('output').textContent = out; ??

Comment: You can either pass the `--name` option to set the name you want to use, or otherwise the default name is the entire path, `controllers/inbox/views/messages`. You can pass the `--pwd` option to adjust this option. Read the API reference linked above.

Comment: using dust.render('messages',data,callback)...i am getting error Error: **Template Not Found: messages**
    at load (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dustjs-linkedin/2.7.2/dust-full.js:189:29)
    at Object.dust.render (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dustjs-linkedin/2.7.2/dust-full.js:100:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/js/custom/inbox/inbox.js:65:6

Comment: javascript files order     'script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dustjs-linkedin/2.7.2/dust-full.js'></script>

     
     <script type="text/javascript" src='/js/custom/inbox/inbox.js'></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src='/js/custom/inbox/messages.js'></script>`